# Bootstrap centered header breaks when header wraps

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a div with a background image and a header that I want centered both horizontally and vertically within the div in front of the image. I have it working on a header that only has one word: Reviews, but when I use the same approach on a header with two words: Custom Slipcovers, it works on medium and up sizes but breaks for mobile: justifying to the left. It seems to only break when the text wraps.

[Centered Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOJBA.jpg)
[Broken for mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpwyh.jpg)

I am using bootstrap 4 and the snippet is of the working code for the Reviews banner. The slipcover banner code is the same on a different page and has the same css just with new class names. Is there a simple fix that I'm missing here? I'd like to avoid making the text smaller in order to keep it on one line as I want to keep the headers uniform in size.

```css
.banner, 
.bannerHeader {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.banner::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(/img/reviews_banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.reviewsHeader {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .banner, 
    .bannerHeader {
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid underNav banner">
    <div class="row bannerHeader align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h1 class="reviewsHeader">Reviews</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here it is working for the shorter header:
[Mobile centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOyv0.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap has a text-center class, could be worth a try like this...  `<h1 class="reviewsHeader text-center">Reviews</h2>` .... I also noticed you're opening with H1 but closing with H2.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up, and thanks for pointing out the closing tag thing, must've started out as h2 and switched to h1 but forgot to switch both. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... As @Cute Code Rob mentioned, you should add `text-center`. Let me know if this works for you.

```css
.banner,
.bannerHeader {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.banner::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(/img/reviews_banner.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.reviewsHeader {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .banner,
  .bannerHeader {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid underNav banner'>
    <div class='row bannerHeader align-items-center justify-content-center'>
      <h1 class='reviewsHeader text-center'>Reviews</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great, knew I was missing something easy